# How not ZF2 parallel login

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework2

I have a application that runs on ZF2 and i have ok authentication and authorization, but i found recently a security gap, i can have parallel logins with parallel sections, when i login a machine, and try to login other the app allows two logins of same user in different machines, some zf expert can tell me what im doing wrong ?

How do i not allow the same user login in other machine using zf2?

Im using `Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable` and trying to do with sessions on DB, this is the best approach?

Comment: How do you know the user is logged in from a certain client? Do you use sessions or some authorization token?

Comment: just the session, but looking for it i found that i need to store that in database anyway, just ask to be sure if that was the best approach

Comment: Then you simply have several sessions, each client has its own. When a client logs out then you destroy the session and when all clients are logged out your user is offline. No problem IMO.

Comment: Yeah, i did similar, when user log in i store when (timestamp) in database, then each interaction update that, if i have some timeout i conclude that user has gonna way and let the same credentials log in again, just because in that system i have number of user per client limitated